# Derivative of a trace with second order Kronecker product

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, kronecker-product

I am trying to compute the derivative of $J$ with respect to $F$.
when
$$
J = \mathrm{Tr}\lbrack(I_{N} \otimes F)^{T}A(I_{N} \otimes F)B\rbrack
$$
$$
F \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times Nn},\ \  A \in \mathbb{R}^{NN \times NN}, \ \ B \in \mathbb{R}^{NNn \times NNn}
$$
$ B$ is a symmetric matrix

I have noted there are similar posts regarding the derivative involving the trace of a Kronecker product.
But I am not sure how to solve it when there is a second-order equation. 
Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
X &= I\otimes F \\
G &= (A+A^T)XB \\
}$$
Then the cost function can be written as
$$\eqalign{
{\cal J} &= A^TX:XB \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$M:N = {\rm Tr}(M^TN)$$
Next calculate the differential of the cost function.
$$\eqalign{
d{\cal J}
 &= A^TdX:XB + A^TX:dX\,B \\
 &= dX:AXB + A^TXB:dX \\
 &= (A+A^T)XB:dX \\
 &= G:dX \\
 &= G:(I\otimes dF) \\
}$$
At this point, calculate the SVD of $G$
$$\eqalign{
&G = \sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_ku_kv_k^T \\
&u_k \in {\mathbb R}^{NN\times 1},\quad
&r,\sigma_k \in {\mathbb R} \\
&v_k \in {\mathbb R}^{NNn\times 1},\quad 
&r = {\rm rank}(G) \\
}$$
Reshape the singular vectors into matrices
(unstack ${\tt1}$ column into $N$ columns)
$$\eqalign{
U_k &= {\rm Reshape}(u_k,\,\,N\times N)\;&\iff\;  u_k&= {\rm vec}(U_k) \\
V_k &= {\rm Reshape}(v_k,\,Nn\times N) \;&\iff\;\;v_k&= {\rm vec}(V_k) \\
}$$
and use them to finish the calculation of the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
d{\cal J}
 &= \sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_ku_kv_k^T:(I\otimes dF) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_ku_k^T(I\otimes dF)v_k \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_k{\rm vec}(U_k)^T{\rm vec}(dF\,V_k) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_kU_k:(dF\,V_k) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_kU_kV_k^T:dF \\
\frac{\partial{\cal J}}{\partial F} &= \sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_kU_kV_k^T \\
}$$

#### Update

Based on the results of 
[this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3735523/),
we can calculate the solution without 
resorting to the SVD of $G$. Instead we'll use a decomposition involving the standard basis $E$-matrices
$$\eqalign{
G &\in {\mathbb R}^{JK\times PQ},\qquad
   E_{kq} \in {\mathbb R}^{K\times Q},\quad
   C_{kq} \in {\mathbb R}^{J\times P} \\
G &= \sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{q=1}^{Q} C_{kq}\otimes E_{kq} \\
C_{kq} &= \sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{p=1}^{P} G_{(jK-K+k)(pQ-Q+q)}\;E_{jp} \\
}$$
Note that the trace of each $C_{kq}$ coefficient is a sum over a few elements of $G$
$$\eqalign{
{\rm Tr}(C_{kq}) &= \sum_{j=1}^{J} G_{(jK-K+k)(jQ-Q+q)} \\
}$$
Set $\,(J,K,P,Q)\to(N,N,N,Nn)\,$ so that the matrices 
$\,(C_{kq},I)\,$ will have the same dimensions, as will $\,(E_{kq},F).\,$
Then recalculate the gradient
$$\eqalign{
d{\cal J} &= G:(I\otimes dF) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{q=1}^{Nn}\;(C_{kq}\otimes E_{kq}):(I\otimes dF) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{q=1}^{Nn}\;(C_{kq}:I)\,(E_{kq}:dF) \\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{q=1}^{Nn}\;
   E_{kq}\;{\rm Tr}(C_{kq})\right):dF\\
\frac{\partial{\cal J}}{\partial F}
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{q=1}^{Nn}\;E_{kq}\,{\rm Tr}(C_{kq}) \\
}$$
This expression *appears* more complicated than the previous one, however it can be evaluated using nothing more than the (shuffled and summed) elements of $G$.

The formula for the components of the gradient show this quite clearly
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial{\cal J}}{\partial F_{kq}}
 \;=\; {\rm Tr}(C_{kq})
 \;=\; \sum_{j=1}^{N} G_{(jN-N+k)(jnN-nN+q)} \\\\
}$$

---

Here's a way to express the gradient without requiring *any* factorizations.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial{\cal J}}{\partial F}
 \;=\; \sum_{k=1}^N\;
\big(e_k^T\otimes I_N\big)\,
\big(A+A^T\big)\,\big(I\otimes F\big)\,B\,
\big(e_k\otimes I_{Nn}\big) \\
}$$
where $e_k$ is the $k^{th}$ column of $I_N$

Comment: Thnks for clear explanation.!!!!!