# Frobenius norm involving Kronecker Product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, kronecker-product

Consider $ J = ||\mathbf{G} - ( \mathbf{B} \otimes \mathbf{X} )||_F^2 $, where $\mathbf{G}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are complex matrices, and $||.||_F$ is the Frobenius norm. Find the derivative with respect to $ \mathbf{X} $

Note: My question is related to this post: [Derivative of a trace with second order Kronecker product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725646/derivative-of-a-trace-with-second-order-kronecker-product). I would like a solution that does not involve SVD decomposition. Any help/hints on how to solve this problem are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ denote the Frobenius inner product $\langle A,B \rangle = A:B = \operatorname{Tr}(AB^T)$. One approach is to expand $J(X + H)$, then extract the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative).  In this case, we have
$$
J(X + H) = \langle G - (B \otimes (X + H)), G - (B \otimes (X+ H)) \rangle\\
= \langle (G - (B \otimes X)) - B \otimes H, (G - (B \otimes X)) - B \otimes H \rangle\\
= J(X) - 2 \operatorname{Re} \langle G - (B \otimes X),B \otimes H \rangle + o(H).
$$
So, the derivative of $J$ with respect to $X$ is
$$
J'(X)(H) = - 2 \operatorname{Re} \langle G - (B \otimes X),B \otimes H \rangle.
$$
The trick, however, is to extract the matrix form of this derivative. For the [numerator-layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Numerator-layout_notation) derivative, we're looking for a matrix $\frac{\partial J}{\partial X} = M$ (that depends on $X$) for which $\langle M,H \rangle = J'(X)(H)$.

The post you linked explains how this matrix can be found using SVD. For another approach, we can use the fact that $M_{ij} = J'(X)(E_{ij})$, where $E_{ij}$ denotes the matrix with a $1$ as the $E_{ij}$ entry and zeros elsewhere. We therefore have
$$
M_{ij} = - 2 \operatorname{Re} \langle G - (B \otimes X),B \otimes E_{ij} \rangle.
$$
We can make a bit more sense out of this if we break $G$ into a sum. If $X$ has size $m \times n$, then we can write
$$
G = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n G_{ij} \otimes E_{ij},
$$
where each $G_{ij}$ has the same size as $B$ (note that $G_{ij}$ is actually a submatrix of $G$). With that, we have
$$
M_{ij} = - 2 \operatorname{Re} \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n G_{ij} \otimes E_{ij} - (B \otimes X),B \otimes E_{ij} \right\rangle\\
= - 2 \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n\operatorname{Re} \left\langle G_{ij} \otimes E_{ij} - (B \otimes X),B \otimes E_{ij} \right\rangle\\
= - 2  \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \operatorname{Re}[\langle G_{ij},B \rangle - \langle B,B\rangle x_{ij}].
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If now, I want to find the $ X $ that minimizes $ J $, would that be $ x_{ij} = tr(G_{ij} B^T) / tr(B B^T) $?

Comment: @Duns Is $X$ a real matrix or is it complex? If it's complex, then $J$ is not complex-differentiable, but we can consider the derivative relative to the real and imaginary parts of $X$

Comment: @Duns Note that these entries are zero whenever the REAL PART of $\langle G_{ij},B \rangle - \langle B,B\rangle x_{ij}$ is zero

Comment: In my case $ X $ is also complex. Then, shall I split X into real and imaginary parts and follow a simialr procedure as yours?

Comment: @Duns the derivative computation is still valid. Just keep in mind that there will be infinitely many $X$s at which the derivative is zero.

Comment: Fom what you say, I understand that the solution $ X $ that minimizes $ J $ is not unique. Can I say that $ x_{ij} = tr(G_{ij} B^T)/tr(B B^T)$ is one particular minimizer of $ J $.

Comment: @Duns yes you can

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First, recall that the component-wise self-gradient of a matrix is given by
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\grad{X}{X_{ij}} &= E_{ij} \\
}$$
where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix whose $(i,j)$ element is equal to one and all others are equal to zero.

Then, for typing convenience, define the matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
A &= (B\otimes X)-G \\
}$$
and the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
\def\Si{\sum_{i=1}^m}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=1}^n}
P:Q &= \Si\Sj P_{ij}Q_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(P^TQ) \\
P^*:P &= \left\| P \right\|_F^2 \\
}$$

---

Use the above notation to write the objective function,

then calculate its component-wise [Wirtinger gradients](https://www.eurecom.fr/%7Egesbert/papers/matrixdiff.pdf)
$$\eqalign{
\def\J{{\cal J}}
\J &= \left\| A \right\|_F^2 \\
 &= A^*:A \\
d\J &= A^*:dA \\
 &= A^*:(B\otimes dX) \\
\grad{\J}{X_{ij}} &= A^*:(B\otimes E_{ij}) \\
}$$
To construct the full matrix-wise gradient, sum these components with the standard matrix basis (which happens to be the previously defined $E_{ij}$ matrices)
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\J}{X} &= \Si\Sj\left(\grad{\J}{X_{ij}}\right)E_{ij} \\
}$$
Of course, gradients with respect to the complex conjugates also exist
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\J}{X_{ij}^*} &= \left(\grad{\J}{X_{ij}}\right)^*
\quad\implies\quad
\grad{\J}{X^*} &= \left(\grad{\J}{X}\right)^* \\
}$$