# How to calculate the coefficients in this matrix decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

This [recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3734116/357854) contained an interesting Kronecker decomposition of the form
$$\eqalign{
&A = \sum_{i,j} C_{ij}\otimes E_{ij} \;\in\;{\mathbb R}^{mp\times nq} \\
&C_{ij} \in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n}\quad\big({\rm Coefficient\,Matrices}\big) \\
&E_{ij} \in{\mathbb R}^{p\times q}\;\quad\big({\rm Standard\,Basis\,Matrices}\big)
}$$
This decomposition has two trivial cases.

When $m=n=1$, the coefficients are simply scalars equal to the components of the matrix $$C_{ij}=A_{ij}$$
When $p=q=1$, then there is only one matrix-valued coefficient equal to the whole matrix  $$C_{11}=A$$
But what is the algorithm/formula to calculate the coefficient matrices in the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the standard basis vectors using an index which
acts as a mnemonic for their dimensionality, i.e.
$$e_j\in{\mathbb R}^{J},\quad e_k\in{\mathbb R}^{K},\quad etc$$
The Kronecker product of two basis vectors
yields a basis vector from a higher dimension
$$\eqalign{
e_\ell &= vec(e_ke_j^T) = e_j\otimes e_k \\
}$$
and reveals the following relationship between the three indexes
$$\eqalign{
&\ell = k + (j-1)K,\quad
&j = 1 + {\rm div}(\ell-1,K),\quad
&k = 1 + {\rm mod}(\ell-1,K) \\
}$$
First, expand an arbitrary vector in the standard basis.
$$\eqalign{
a &\in {\mathbb R}^{L},\qquad L=JK \\
a &= \sum_{\ell=1}^{L} a_\ell e_\ell
 \;=\; \sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{k=1}^{K} a_{(jK-K+k)}\; e_j\otimes e_k  \\
}$$
Next, expand an arbitrary *matrix* in terms of
the standard matrix basis.
$$\eqalign{
A &\in {\mathbb R}^{L\times P},\qquad L=JK,\;P=MN,\quad 
E_{jm} \in {\mathbb R}^{J\times M},\quad
E_{kn} \in {\mathbb R}^{K\times N} \\
A &= \sum_{\ell=1}^{L} \sum_{p=1}^{P} A_{\ell p}\; E_{\ell p}
 \;=\; \sum_{\ell=1}^{L} \sum_{p=1}^{P} A_{\ell p}\; e_\ell e_p^T \\
  &= \left(\sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{k=1}^{K}\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^{M}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\right)
     A_{(jK-K+k)(mN-N+n)}\; (e_j\otimes e_k) (e_m\otimes e_n)^T \\
  &= \sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{m=1}^{M}\sum_{n=1}^{N} 
     A_{(jK-K+k)(mN-N+n)}\; E_{jm}\otimes E_{kn} \\
}$$
So this is the $(JM\times KN)$ decomposition.
There are also $(KN\times JM)$, $\,(JN\times KM)$, and $\,(KM\times JN)$
decompositions. In fact, there are decompositions corresponding to every
possible factorization of the integers $L$ and $P$.

So to answer the question that I posed (with slightly different indexing),
the coefficient matrices of the decompositions
$$\eqalign{
A &= \sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{m=1}^M E_{jm}\otimes B_{jm} \\
  &= \sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{n=1}^N C_{kn}\otimes E_{kn} \\
}$$
are given by
$$\eqalign{
B_{jm}
  &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{n=1}^{N} A_{(jK-K+k)(mN-N+n)}
  \; E_{kn}\right)&\in {\mathbb R}^{K\times N} \\
C_{kn}
  &= \left(\sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{m=1}^{M} A_{(jK-K+k)(mN-N+n)}
  \; E_{jm}\right)&\in {\mathbb R}^{J\times M} \\
}$$
Often, it is the traces of these coefficients
which are of primary interest.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm Tr}(B_{jm}) &= \sum_{k=1}^{K} A_{(jK-K+k)(mN-N+k)} \\
{\rm Tr}(C_{kn}) &= \sum_{j=1}^{J} A_{(jK-K+k)(jN-N+n)} \\
\\
}$$

---

An important special case occurs when $N=1$
$$\eqalign{
E_{kn} &= e_k \\
C_{kn} &= C_k \\
A &= \sum_{k=1}^K C_{k}\otimes e_{k} \\
}$$
The coefficient matrices and their traces reduce to  
$$\eqalign{
C_{k} &= \sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{m=1}^{M} A_{(k-K+Kj)(m)}\; E_{jm} \\
{\rm Tr}(C_{k}) &= \sum_{j=1}^{J} A_{(k-K+Kj)(j)} \\
}$$
Repeating this analysis for $M=1$ yields
$$\eqalign{
E_{jm} &= e_j \\
B_{jm} &= B_j \\
A &= \sum_{j=1}^J e_{j}\otimes B_{j} \\
B_{j} &= \sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{n=1}^{N} A_{(jK-K+k)(n)}\; E_{kn} \\
{\rm Tr}(B_{j}) &= \sum_{k=1}^{K} A_{(jK-K+k)(k)} \\
}$$